# Buffered Reader inFromUser.Read() Type

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I was wondering what is the type of `read()` in `BufferedReader`. I really need to know in order to fix my code because it is creating errors. Thank you in advance

Comment: [`BufferedReader#read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--): *Reads a single character. **Returns:** The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached*

Comment: changed to exact method/class names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type is **int** of read() method in BufferedReader

```
int read()
```

Reads a single character.

**Returns:**

The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

```
int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
```

Reads characters into a portion of an array.

**Returns:**

The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached

Refer the java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html